# iOS MapKit - showAnnotations to Include User Location on Zoom

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

I have a network call in viewDidAppear that retrieves a list of sites containing location information to be displayed on a map. When calling showAnnotations the map will zoom to show all annotations **excluding** the user's location.

Other Stack Overflow questions say to call showAnnotations with the animated flag as true, but this doesn't work.

```
// Assign new sites
self.sites = newSites

// Show annotations on map
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.sites, animated: true)
```

Why does this only zoom to show sites but not the user's location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that showAnnotations will add the annotations to the map and only zoom to show those - which makes perfect sense. So how can we include the user's location? I did it with the following code:

```
// Assign new sites
self.sites = newSites

// Add new annotations
self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.sites)

// Show all annotations to include current user location
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

The key part here is to add the annotations using mapView.addAnnotations first, then call mapView.showAnnotations(..., animated: true) on all the mapView's annotations which includes the user's location.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning, `mapView.showUserLocation=true` must be called before `showAnnotations`